# UIImagePicker in one view, send selected image to a second view

Tags: iphone

In my main view controller I have a button that prompts the user to select a photo from their photo library then display it (img), which looks like this:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
img.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];}
```

My question is how can I also display this selected image in a second view controller? I know how to go to a different view, I'm just unsure how to send an image to that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this in .h file in SecondViewController

```
UIImage *imgSelected;
```

Make below function in seconviewcontroller

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)imgCaptured{
    imgSelected=imgCaptured;
}
```

Now In first view controller do like this:

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller has been instantiated already i.e. it is below the current view controller in the navigation stack, you can consider [`delegates`](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) or [`notifications`](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html).

If it is yet to be created then save the image in an instance variable and pass it along when you push the next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
example


firstviewcontroller .h file

        before @interface 

        use @class secondViewcontroller;


declare this inside of @interface  with

        secondViewcontroller *sVC;


then in firstViewController.m file 

        before @implementation

        use 

    #import "secondViewcontroller.h"


then




-------------------

secondVC.h file

        @interface inside declare this

        say UIImage *secondimage;

        and sythasize them.








-------------------


after this 

        in firstViewcontroller.h viewdidload create this sVC by alloc and initwithnibname then

        sVC.secondimage=urfirstImage;

        now while u push this sVC controller to navigation controller u can show that in UIImageView.
```